# blender 2.8 - array modifier doesn't follow curve

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I want to build a simple race track. I have created a closed bezier curve. Then I have added a plane object with curve modifier. When I try to apply array modifier planes don't follow a curve. What is wrong ? [image: screenshot]

Comment: did you try moving the curve modifier below the array and changing the fit type of the array to curve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the *Curve* modifier below the *Array* modifier